# rails 4 page index cache creates a index.html instead of model.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I Have a model named `product` and I intend to implement page caching on the index action.

In my Gemfile I have included

```
gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
```

in my controller I have

```
caches_page :index
```

in my routes.rb I have

```
resources :products, :path => "toys"
```

Issue:
In my `public` directory the html file that is being created is named `index.html` as compared to the expected 'products.html' or 'toys.html'

This problem hurts me when I `expire_page products_path` on a successful product create/update, the application looks for a `products.html` or 'toys.html' to delete, but cannot find it and effectively the cache is not flushed.

Does anyone know why would rails 4 name the cached page `index.html`?

Comment: What do you have in routes.rb ?

Comment: My answer solve your problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Because it is still searching for the `<model>s.html` named file and no search file is present.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in update an create action:

```
expire_page action: 'index'
```